nextjs warning he resource app_ui_9f9577._.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event
I have a nextjs application that uses tailwind css and I get a strange warning since upgrading to nextjs 15 as this:
The resource http://myserver:3000/_next/static/chunks/app_ui_9f9577._.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

If I inspect the browser for the given source on _next/static/chunks I find these lines:
/* [project]/app/ui/global.css [app-client] (css) */
*, :before, :after {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x: ;
  --tw-pan-y: ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
  --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
  --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
  --tw-ordinal: ;
  --tw-slashed-zero: ;
  --tw-numeric-figure: ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
  --tw-ring-inset: ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: #0070f380;
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur: ;
  --tw-brightness: ;
  --tw-contrast: ;
  --tw-grayscale: ;
  --tw-hue-rotate: ;
  --tw-invert: ;
  --tw-saturate: ;
  --tw-sepia: ;
  --tw-drop-shadow: ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia: ;
  --tw-contain-size: ;
  --tw-contain-layout: ;
  --tw-contain-paint: ;
  --tw-contain-style: ;
}

no idea what is going on here, any suggestions ? thanks
